# Passing SQL connections to objects

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, parameters, connection

Note: Not a java EE question

In java, I need to pass an SQL Connection  from one class to another as a parameter.
But it seems that the receiving class gets the Connection object but it is null and not connected.

I read java EE uses a pool. But my project is small with a localhost connection using the Driver manager of JDBC.
Also I read java does no pass by reference.

Any way I can pass a live connection from one class to another?

EDIT:
IN CLASS CONNECT

```
try
  {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      connect = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost/MYDATABASE?user="+username+"&password="+password);
return connect;
  }catch(Exception e){
      return null;
```

IN MY MAIN CLASS

```
connect c = new connect(user,pass);
```

Comment: Show us the code so we can help you better (besides, passing a connection to another object is __ugly__)

Comment: Show us some code , where and how you are passing . You can have a ConnectionManager class and other class can request Connection object from that class.

Comment: If the receiving class gets a null, then you're passing it a null. The parameters can't magically become null by themselves.

Comment: @Kayaman I have no idea. That is what actually happened.
I tried executing a query inide my first class and it worked.
In my second class the same query throws a null pointer exception !

Comment: @TheNewIdiot A code snippet

Comment: @XperiazX `catch(Exception e){ return null; }` is what's happening. Add `e.printStackTrace();` and see for yourself.

Comment: Now you should have learned why its bad to catch an Exception and not properly handle it! Your caller gets a `null` with no idea what happened. If you have no idea what to do with an exception, you should at least rethrow it as `RuntimeException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Connect
{
private static Connection sharedConnection;
public static Connection createOrAccessConnection(String user,String pass, boolean forceNew){ 
Connection connect = sharedConnection;
try
  {

      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      if(forceNew || connect == null)
         { 
              connect = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost/MYDATABASE?user="+username+"&password="+password);
              if(sharedConnection == null ) 
                { 
                sharedConnection = connect; 
                }  
         }
return connect;
  }catch(Exception e){
      return null;
}
}



class Main
   {
   public void transactionMethod()
   {
       //Some code here.
       //This is what you need to add.
       Connection con = Connect.createConnection(user,pass,false);
       Sysout(con);
       AnotherClass ac = new AnotherClass();
       ac.operation1(con, false);
       ac.operation1(null,true);  
   }



class AnotherClass
       {
       public void operation1(Connection con, boolean createNew) 
            {
            if(createNew || con==null)
               {
               con = Connect.createConnection(user,pass,false);
               }
            //Some code here
            if(createNew)
               {
               //Close connection here. 
               }      
            }
       } 

       }
```

Comment: Above code should solve your problem. Also, note that it facilitates creation of connection at static load time and dynamically as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you've already done it correctly, but it's simply a case of *using* the method, there is no *trick* to it.

```
class A
{
    Connection connection;

    public void setConnection( Connection connection )
    {
        if ( connection == null ) System.out.println("null passed!");
        this.connection = connection;
    }
}
```

Now you simply call the method, that's it:

```
Connection c = null;
// TODO: added code here to establish the connection.
A a = new A();
if ( c == null ) System.out.println("c is null before passing it on!");
a.setConnection(c);
```

If the value being passed is `null` (not connected), then you need to look at the code that creates the connection, to make sure you're passing a valid (connected) object through.

EDIT
I just saw the code snippet that you added. If that `try {...} catch`  is within your constructor, then it won't work ... shouldn't even compile! The constructor can not be used to return a value, only methods can.

Comment: This really did help me.
My problem was that a Connection, as a member in my main class (public or private) could never be passed to other objects. (maybe because it was static but still have no clue why)
But a locally created non static Connection could be easily passed and received.

Answer (score 1):

- I can tell that you are not creating connection in Constructor because of return statement.

Please have a look below:

```
class Connect
{
public Connection createConnection(){ 
try
  {
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      connect = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost/MYDATABASE?user="+username+"&password="+password);
return connect;
  }catch(Exception e){
      return null;
}
}



class Main
   {
   public void connectionNeededHere()
   {
       //Some code here.
       ...
       //This is what your are calling. 
       Connect c = new connect(user,pass);
       //This is what you need to add.
       Connection con = c.createConnection();
       Sysout(con);
   }

   }
```

Comment: `class`, not Class for both Connect and Main ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.
But my problem was passing data member of main class to another class.